# JS cycle plugin not working in IE11. Object doesn't support property or method 'cycle'

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, internet-explorer-11

I have used the plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ and I have tried using the new one(Cycle2) and the old one. The old one is the one currently being used and it works on all browsers EXCEPT IE11. It even works on the older versions of IE but not the latest one. This is getting very frustrating. I have researched this for 2 days now and no luck. Any help is much appreciated. Below is the code that it fails at:

```
if ($("#home").length >= 1) {
    yepnope({
        load: '/js/plugins/jquery.cycle.all.js',
        complete: function() {
            //intro animation
            var baseT = 3500;
            $("#intro img").fadeOut(baseT + 1000, function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "/images/intro_cleaner.jpg").fadeIn(100);
            });
            $("#intro h1").animate({
                left: '-1745px'
            }, baseT, function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(750);
                $("#intro").fadeOut(baseT, function() {
                    $("#home .stories").show();
                });
            });

            //featured stories
            $("#home .stories").cycle({
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                prev: '#prev',
                next: '#next',
                timeout: baseT + 7000,
                before: function(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
                    $("#total-slides").text(opts.slideCount);
                    $("#slide-num").text($(next).index() + 1);
                }
            });
```

Comment: wonder if it's a `yepnope` load event problem triggering `complete` too soon. Try wrapping plugin initalize in `setTimeout` to delay it a bit more

Comment: How do I do that? I am pretty new to JS.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ $("#home .stories").cycle({....});}, 500)`

Comment: Adding that in made another error, similar to the first one, appear.

Comment: Hard to help without specific error information

Comment: Sorry about that. The error is pretty much the same but with another method that was working before I added the setTimeout to the first code. Object doesn't support property or method 'objectOverlay'

Comment: but where does that error come from....should show source in console output

Comment: if ($("a.video").length >= 1) {
        yepnope({
            load: '/js/plugins/jquery.objectOverlay.js',
            complete: function() {
                $('a.video').objectOverlay();

            }
        });
    }

Object doesn't support property or method 'objectOverlay'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and debugging, I have found the reason is that yepnope is not loading the JS file needed to run the method cycle. To fix this, I just posted script tags that load the JS file. This will probably slow down the site but I needed a quick fix since this was a production issue. I found that yepnope is deprecated and the code in it is not supported in IE11. Found this through http://yepnopejs.com/
There are alternatives to yepnope such as http://headjs.com/
Hope others find this useful.